# nth-child for multiple children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to get the nth-child selector to work. I need to apply some css to the first and secnd children, then the 6th and 7th, then the 11th and 12th, then the 16th and 17th and so on.

The first two I can get with :nth-child(-n+2), but how do I get the other ones, or is there an even better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
p:nth-child(5n + 1), p:nth-child(5n + 2)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6xgzLs5/